# Getting ordered value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Series:

```
ser = pd.Series({'a': 10, 'b': 21, 'c': 12, 'd': 5, 'e': 26, 'd': 17})
```

Which method can I use to identify the order of an element relative to others? For example, if I sort the Series in ascending order `c` is in the second position.

Comment: `percentile` is probably not what you want, but relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) method:

```
ser.rank()
Out[178]: 
a    1.0
b    4.0
c    2.0
d    3.0
e    5.0
dtype: float64
```